# Char pointers pointing to an int variable

Tags: c, pointers, casting

```
int i=10;
char *ptr = &i;
printf("%d",*ptr); // what will be the output and why
*ptr =11; //now what will be the output and why
```

Can anyone help me with this ?? I'm getting different output and I don't know why. Can anyone explain me what is happening here and why ??

Comment: *I'm getting different output* **What** output?

Comment: You're invoking undefined behavior all around, that's what's happening.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this? Seriously don't do weird things.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I don't see the UB, but `ptr = &i` looks like a type error to me.

Comment: @melpomene I was thinking of that `printf`, "all around" may have been a bit too much.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca when `char` is passed to `printf` it is promoted to `int` anyway.

Comment: @WeatherVane I really need to re-look at the standard before commenting, shame on me.

Answer (score 3):

Let's break this down a bit.

```
int i = 10;
```

We now have a variable, `i`, with a 10 in it. This variable is several bytes long — let's say 4 for the sake of the argument (and because it is the most common value). 10 fits in a single byte, so the least significant byte will be 10 and the rest will be zero. But the least significant byte can be the first (little-endian) or the last (big-endian) — that's defined by the compiler, the underlying CPU, etc.

```
char * ptr = &i;
```

...is an error, or at least a warning. Let's fix it:

```
char * ptr = (char *) &i;
```

Normally, using a pointer of the wrong type is *undefined behavior*, meaning that the compiler can emit code that does *anything it wants* for it. But there's an exception for `char` — you can legally cast any object pointer to `char *` (or `signed char *` or `unsigned char *`). So `ptr` now points to the first byte of `i`.

```
printf("%d", *ptr);
```

...is not correct. `*ptr` is of type `char`, but `%d` is used for an `int`. Let's fix it:

```
printf("%hhd", *ptr);
```

Now, remember that `ptr` points to the first byte of `i`. Also remember that `i` has a byte equal to 10 and several bytes equal to zero, and the 10 could be first or last. So this prints either 10 or 0. Which one? It's *implementation-defined*.

```
*ptr = 11;
```

If the previous line printed 10, then the first byte was the least significant one — which you just set to 11, making `i` equal 11.

If the previous line printed zero, you just set the most significant byte to 11. This will set `i` to some very large value.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `printf("%d", *ptr)`. `char` values will be promoted to `int` before being passed to varargs functions, so `printf` will receive an `int` anyway.

Comment: @melpomene There isn't, but some values (particularly when signed/unsigned conversions are involved) can lead to issues, so it's better to get the hang of doing it right. (Consider a machine with `char` being signed passing a value of 200. `%hhu` will print 200; `%u` will print 4294967240 (assuming a four-byte `int`).)

Comment: If `char` is signed (and 8 bits wide), it can't have a value of 200.

Comment: @melpomene `char foo = 200;` will silently truncate the value to -56. Not sure if it is UB, but it _will_ work in just about any platform.

Comment: The behavior of that is implementation defined. But in any case you're lying to printf (passing a negative value to an unsigned format specification).